# DISTINCT from One table and INNER JOIN with another table in snowflake

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to:

- Join two tables
- Remove "queryGroupName" = 'DELETE' from the first table
- From the first table, get Id by deduping (distinct ID)
- Using this Id, inner join with another table
- For output, select only the second table

SELECT "TABLE2".*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "Id" FROM DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE1")
INNER JOIN DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE2" ON DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE1"."Id" = DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE2"."Id"
WHERE "queryGroupName" not in ('DELETE');

I'm getting following error message:

> SQL compilation error: error line 4 at position 3 invalid identifier
> 'DB1.PUBLIC.TABLE1."Id"'

Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the goal is to use JOIN on T1 table only as a filter, IN/EXISTS could be used:

```
SELECT T2.*
FROM DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE2" AS T2 
WHERE T2."Id" IN (SELECT T1."Id" FROM DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE1" AS T1)
  AND T2."queryGroupName" NOT IN ('DELETE');
```

Comment: Thank you.  I edited a bit of your query and it solved the issue.

Comment: Here is my answer:

SELECT *
FROM DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE2"
WHERE DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE2"."Id" IN 
(SELECT DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE1"."Id" from BW."PUBLIC"."TABLE1" where "queryGroupName" NOT IN ('DELETE'))

Answer (score 1):

TABLE1 is not in the main query. It's part of a subquery. If you alias the subquery, you can reference it by the alias.

```
SELECT "TABLE2".*
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "Id" FROM DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE1") T1
INNER JOIN DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE2" ON T1."Id" = DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE2"."Id"
WHERE "queryGroupName" not in ('DELETE');
```

Comment: I'd add on that it would make the query much cleaner if they add an alias for the second table as well. I would also say they could remove the ugly quotes, but it's looking like they've got case sensitive column names which means it's stuck that way..

Comment: Thank you Greg and David. I tried Greg's script and it gave me an error message: SQL compilation error: error line 5 at position 6 invalid identifier '"queryGroupName"'. I believe this is because I'm only selecting the "Id" from the T1 and the "queryGroupName" is from T1. If I add "queryGroupName" in this line: FROM (SELECT DISTINCT "Id","queryGroupName" FROM DB1."PUBLIC"."TABLE1") T1 I get a wrong number of rows because some of the rows are double counted.

Comment: It is an INNER JOIN, so if there are multiple matches, there will be multiple rows returned in the result.